# How to vertical align <input> and <iframe> inside <td>?(demo included)

Tags: html-table, vertical-alignment

The page is very simple here:

http://maishudi.com/test.php

Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
    <input type="text" />
    <iframe scrolling="no" height="21px" frameborder="0" width="62px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="Server/SecCode.php">
    </iframe>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [maishudi.com](http://maishudi.com/screen.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use two td's, one for the input, and one for the iframe:

- [Sample 1](http://jsbin.com/izino)

Or don't use tables at all, position the items using CSS, with the [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp) property:

- [Sample 2](http://jsbin.com/axoju)

Answer (score 0):

Use **valign** attribute of **td** tag.

```
..
<td valign="top">

</td>
```

EDIT:

Try this,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><iframe scrolling="no" height="21px" 
          frameborder="0" width="62px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
          src="http://maishudi.com/Server/SecCode.php">
    </iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could easily tell us without downvoting.